# Share Xbox Game Pass between two consoles simultaneously

Tags: xbox-one, xbox-network, xbox-game-pass

Is it possible to share Game Pass Ultimate between two consoles at the same time?

I remember when I had two Xbox Ones about 5 years ago, I was able to have a home console and a guest console.

We're looking at getting one of the new Xbox and are hoping to be able to share both the network connectivity ("Gold") and games (via Game Pass) at the same time.

Comment: You may or may not have to set your Ultimate account to home Xbox on both xboxes. I’m pretty sure that you can only have 2 Xbox’s with the same account set as home Xbox. When you set your ultimate account to home Xbox on the other Xbox, download the games you want to play then log onto another account on that 2nd Xbox *if you want to play a game with yourself or between the 2 Xbox’s*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes!**

The Xbox Live infrastructure hasn't changed. You will be able to set the Series X as Home Console via the *Settings -> General -> Personalization* menu where you can set "*My Home Xbox*".

This feature is a feature of the Xbox family and works identically across all Xboxes. Keep in mind that this means that you can have **one** Home Xbox, not one of each kind (i.e. Xbox One and Xbox Series X).

Comment: Spot on. We received it and follows these steps and it did exactly what I was after. I had hoped this might work, I can confirm that it does.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember right, your XBL Gold account is related to your account, and not to your console.

So if you use your account on 2 consoles, then you have XBL Gold (and I would imagine GamePass) on that account on both consoles.

So when you buy the XBox One X everything should follow.

Only thing tho, you cannot play on the account on both consoles at the same time. Logging in the account on one console will log out the account on the other.